# How to close the jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

This is my code i open the page url into the dialog. now i want to  close the dialog from the page default4.aspx that is actually inside the dialog..

In Default4.aspx there is button name close: now i want to close the dialog and also want pass some value to close function :

```
 close: function(event,ui){
here:
  }
```

the code i used:

```
 $("#pop").load('Default4.aspx').dialog({
             height: 625,
             width: 600,
             modal:true,
             close: function(event,ui){


             //alert(event)
             //Check for Ok or cancle
             // if ok then do something

            // alert(ui);

             }
             });
```

Any Idea Guys How Can i do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `$("#pop").dialog("close");` in Default4.aspx

For passing parametrs you can use input hidden element

```
$("#hidden").val("my param value");   
<...> 
var param = $("#hidden").val();
```

Comment: Nothing is happening dude? i try these already.. but the issue is the button on the other page that i pass to dialog....any other idea

Comment: it works fine on my test page! are you sure that $("#pop").dialog("close") is called?

Comment: when you call  $("#pop").load('Default4.aspx').dialog() JQuery just put html code of  Default4 inside div. It`s one html page for the browser. But for the Default4.aspx not fires js document.OnLoad event.

Comment: i don't no why my dialog is not closing i use the same method...even i also use the destroy method but nothing was happen...I create the same that you said i put the all html into the div....but don't know wht wrong with my code?